# AssemblyResolve for GAC'd Assemblies

Tags: .net, gac

I'm trying to put my assembly in the GAC for performance reasons. It has some code that binds to the AssemblyResolve event. However, since GAC'ing my assembly, the AssemblyResolve event handler is no longer hit when the source of the resolution is coming from my own GAC'd assembly.

In other words, my GAC'd assembly has a reference to XYZ.dll. Instead of having to  redistribute it separately, my GAC'd assembly has XYZ.dll stored as an embedded resource that is loaded on startup. The assembly resolution handler returns the dynamically loaded instance of XYZ.dll. However, now that my assembly is GAC'd the AssemblyResolve event doesn't fire for XYZ.dll at all.

I'm guessing it has to do with the load context being different...but I'm not sure how to deal with it. How can I get resolution to work now that my assembly is GAC'd?

Comment: This sounds like a terribly complicated hole to have dug yourself into. Why have you chosen the `AssemblyResolve` event to load the dependency? Why is the dependency an embedded resource instead of standard CLR assembly?

Comment: Is XYZ.dll in the GAC as well? I would attach to the process that should have loaded your assembly and XYZ.dll and see where it is loaded from.

Comment: @ProgrammingHero This kind of standard if you want to merge assemblies but don't want to/can't use ILMerge. see http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Comment: It's more of a deployment issue. Deploying 15 assemblies is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: And to answer the question mike, yes I can clearly see the dll has loaded via AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(). AssemblyResolve just isn't giving me the chance to choose the dll.

Comment: @mikez I was hoping for an answer that would clarify that there was a good enough reason for trying to do this. Rather than having the problem of maintaining a deployment of 15 assemblies, now you have to maintain embedding and dynamically loading 15 assemblies.

Comment: It's easy for me to maintain the 15 assemblies. Making sure all of my customers/clients get those assemblies distributed and installed is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, this doesn't work.  The GAC is a DLL Hell counter-measure, it ensures that any app that relies on a specific version of a DLL gets the specific version of the DLL they asked for.  Consistently, no matter what process asked for it.  Allowing the dependencies of the GAC-ed DLL to be resolved in the probing path of the process would bring back DLL Hell in the worst possible way.  It completely defeats the guarantee that the GAC provides, the DLL can now *not* be trusted to work consistently.

This is not just subtle either, a basically scary scenario is where the base class of a derived class that's defined in an assembly that's GAC-ed is defined in a dependent assembly.  What you hope to work will allow a *completely* different base class implementation.  There are reasonable odds that the jitter won't fall over if the base class isn't too different.  The actual outcome at runtime is quite miserable, the wrong code executes with few ways to diagnose why, especially to a user without a debugger.  DLL Hell is a user nightmare, the person least capable of diagnosing and fixing the problem is the victim.

The CLR categorically refuses to let you shoot the user's foot this way.  Yes, loading context is the key, Fusion is the underlying api.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wouldn't say the GAC is such a strong counter measure to dll hell. It's just another form of it. I guess I'll have to deploy my other dlls into the GAC too if I want to go this route.

Comment: Well, yes, the GAC gets in the way when you *want* DLL Hell by design.

Comment: All I really wanted was a way out of having to redistribute 15 dlls as opposed to just 1. My clients want a black box, not a million dlls and dependencies.

Comment: Because then you have another set of problems - do I tell my client to download the System.Reactive framework and install it prior to installing my dll? Or do I redistribute it with my dll's MSI? And if I do, that means I take ownership of it, which isn't good. And what about Castle Windsor? I guess I need to put that in the GAC with my dll...but what if another application on the computer uses Windsor and has Specific Version set to false? I potentially just broke their application. Same thing with Entity Framework 4.1. Or ASP .NET MVC 3. DLL Hell is alive and well.

Comment: I only put the assembly in the GAC for faster startup times. As far as I'm concerned the GAC really only works well for System assemblies...but having my dll in there really seems to improve cold start times.